# Exporting data from JTable into PDF format

Tags: java, itext

I want to extract data that's inside of a JTable to a pdf file when a user clicks a button.

Below is my code:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("table.pdf"));
        doc.open();
        PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(table.getColumnCount());
        //adding table headers
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            pdfTable.addCell(table.getColumnName(i));
        }
        //extracting data from the JTable and inserting it to PdfPTable        
        for (int rows = 0; rows < table.getRowCount() - 1; rows++) {
            for (int cols = 0; cols < table.getColumnCount(); cols++) {
                pdfTable.addCell(table.getModel().getValueAt(rows, cols).toString());
            }
        }
        doc.add(pdfTable);
        doc.close();
        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your PDF generation code looks fine, Assuming u have the file getting generated on disk. You can use the below to download the file

```
import java.io.*;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  

public class ExportJtable extends HttpServlet {    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                throws ServletException, IOException {  
        response.setContentType("text/pdf");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
        String filename = "table.pdf";   
        String filepath = "/user/home";   
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");   

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath + filename);  

        int i;   
        while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
        out.write(i);   
        }   
        fileInputStream.close();   
        out.close();   
    }  
}
```

Comment: *"Assuming u have the file getting generated on disk. You can use the below to download the file"* - reading the question I see no hint that the OP wants to do that.